# Vector of shared pointers updates existing elements on push_back

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

Basically, I have a vector of `shared_ptr` as member data to a class.
This vector is populated by calling a member function from another class function.
Problem new elements added to the vector updates values of existing elements.

The setup is as follows:

**class A**

```
/*
 * Class A has a header with class declarations and a distinct implementation.
 * For the sake of brevity, the relevant information is shown in this snippet.
 */
class A {
public:
    A(std::string name) : m_name(name);
    std::string& get_name();
private:
    std::string m_name;
}
typedef std::shared_ptr<A> A_ptr;
```

**class B**

```
/*
 * Class B has a header with class declarations and a distinct implementation.
 * For the sake of brevity, the relevant information is shown in this snippet.
 */
class B {
public:
    void add_element(A_ptr& element) {
        /*
         this is where the problem is:
         i DO get the proper element (i can verify this by calling the get_name() method on `element`).

         Assume we got in succession:
         - ONE
         - TWO
         - THREE

         ...
        */
        std::cout << element -> get_name << std::endl;

        m_elements.push_back(element);

        /*
         ...

         fast forward here, when I print the content of the vector held in this class,
         the old elements added have been updated somehow and I get this:

         - when we get ONE, the vector contains: [ONE]
         - when we get TWO on the next call to this function, the vector contains: [TWO, TWO]. I expect [ONE,TWO]
         - when we get THREE on the next call to this function, the vector contains: [THREE, THREE, THREE]. I expect [ONE, TWO, THREE]

         -> WHAT ON EARTH IS GOING ON HERE?
        */
        for (auto it = m_elements.begin(); it != m_elements.end(); ++it)
            std::cout << (* it) -> get_name() << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::vector<A_ptr> m_elements;
}
typedef std::shared_ptr<B> B_ptr;
```

`class B` is the problem class. In the `add_element()` function, I am getting the proper elements to add (namely `ONE`, `TWO` and `THREE`).
But, after the `push_back()`, not only the new element is added, the existing elements all have their values updated to the new element that got added.
So say I add elements with names `ONE` then `TWO`, instead of getting a vector with elements as `[ONE, TWO]`, I get `[TWO, TWO]`.

**class C**

```
/*
 * Class C has a header with class declarations and a distinct implementation.
 * For the sake of brevity, the relevant information is shown in this snippet.
 */
class C {
public:
    void do_something() {
        std::string name = name_obtained_dynamically();
        B_ptr manager(new B());

        do {
            A_ptr element_one(nullptr);
            A_ptr element_two(nullptr);

            if (we_are_good) {
                element_one.reset(new A(name));
            }
            else {
                element_two.reset(new A(name));
            }

            if (element_one !=nullptr)
                manager -> add_element(element_one);
            else
                manager -> add_element(element_two);
        } while(condition_is_true);
    }
}
```

`class C` calls `add_element()` from `class B` and keeps adding elements to said vector.
So far as I can tell, the problem probably lies with my use of shared pointers inside that loop.
But what exactly I am doing wrong, I cannot tell.

Comment: If you post a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I'm sure someone can give a definitive answer, but a good rule of thumb is *don't put smart pointers in a standard container.* Those containers are designed to handle inert cargo, and smart pointers act more like fussy passengers. I have a list somewhere, of the rules that contained types should obey, if I can just find it...

Comment: cannot replicate http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38adb88dd25809cd

Comment: @Beta Thanks for the advice. And I would love to get my hands on that list, maybe a github repo (or a simple gist) when you find it?  
Still, how do you put said inert cargo in the container when it will get destroyed once it goes out of scope?

Comment: @Sopel That's odd. Will look again at the full code and see if I might have omitted relevant information.

Comment: A full example demonstrating behavior in question is a must here. I suspect that somewhere in the code, which has been omitted, you break the rules of using iterators along with vector modification. This leads to undefined behavior. Make sure that you are aware which operations (like `push_back()`) may invalidate existing iterators.

Comment: @VolodymyrLashko I'm afraid I have only used iterators in the example to print values but nowhere else as part of the logic.
I am indeed trying to create a full (working) example that demonstrates the behavior I am experiencing.

Comment: @VolodymyrLashko After failing to create an example that reproduces my problem, I gave up and followed Beta's advice.

Comment: @Beta Followed your advice, got rid of all smart pointers (leaving one `unique_ptr` where there was no other choice) and I now have the desired behavior. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Regarding your question about cargo: don't keep pointers to things that have gone out of scope. If that seems like a difficult thing to keep track of, then a review of the basics (variables, pointers, arrays, the stack, the heap) might be worthwhile.

Comment: @Beta Yes, heeding your advice, I took the time to review the basics and realized I was needlessly using shared pointers. In fact part of the basics was to ask oneself if pointers are needed at all before using them.
Now I have a single unique  pointer (it is actually needed so the value can survive the function termination). Previously, I had shared pointers scattered all over the place for no good reason.
When possible, I shall write an answer about what I changed so others see if it works for them.
Thanks again for your insight.

Comment: You just made my day.